# Apache Cluster + Tomcat websocket

Tags: apache-2.4, cluster, websocket, ajp, tomcat8

We've recently configured a new Cluster with the following configuration:

```
   www.mydomain.com
           |        
    APACHE + MOD_JK (AJP)
     Load Balancer
      /           \
  Tomcat1      Tomcat2
```

All the requests are made through HTTPS and the two tomcat instances are using SessionReplication via DeltaManager.

The cluster and all the wep-apps are working just fine.

Now one of these webapps requires the use of WebSockets with WSS:// protocol and i'm getting this exception

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: HTTP upgrade is not supported
>   by this protocol

Has anyone ever a clue on what is causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install mod_proxy_wstunnel apache module.

Comment: so now we are using mod_jk and should migrate to a mod_proxy clustering solution ?
Will mod_proxy handle be able to load balance also the WSS:// requests ?

Comment: moved configuration to mod_proxy and all seems to work fine, thanks

Answer (score 3):

As [discussed](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201603.mbox/%3CD1D617C4C2D6425EA292042B32036CEB@prosrm.com%3E) on the tomcat-users mailing list: "[...] the AJP protocol does not support upgrading to other
protocols (e.g. websocket, HTTP/2)."

This means you'd have to use some other method of proxying these connections to your Tomcat instances. As Tux_DEV_NULL mentioned you could use mod_proxy_wstunnel for this.